# On a correspondence between subperiodic and magnetic space groups

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, crystallography

The [Wikipedia article on space groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group) says

> Frieze groups are magnetic 1D line groups and layer groups are magnetic wallpaper groups…

Indeed:

- There are $7$ [frieze groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group) and $7$ magnetic 1D [line groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_group), where a [magnetic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_space_group) is a space group where the domains can also be time-reversed.
- There are $80$ [layer groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_group) and $80$ magnetic [wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group). One day, with too much free time on my hands, I worked out the exact correspondence between these two sets of groups:

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

(The numbers beside each layer/magnetic wallpaper group refer to their number in the International Tables for Crystallography.)

Define an $(n,m)$ space group as a (non-magnetic) space group in $n$ dimensions whose translation lattice is $m$-dimensional. Then the two equivalences mentioned at the beginning of this question may be restated as

- There are as many $(2,1)$ space groups as magnetic $(1,1)$ space groups
- There are as many $(3,2)$ space groups as magnetic $(2,2)$ space groups

The reason for the correspondence seems clear: time reversal corresponds to reflection in a dimension orthogonal to all other dimensions. Based on this, it seemed very reasonable for me to conjecture that

- There are as many $(4,3)$ space groups as magnetic $(3,3)$ space groups

However, this is false. There are $1651$ magnetic $(3,3)$ space groups, but only $1594$ $(4,3)$ space groups. **How does the discrepancy arise?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[B. Souvignier (2006), "The four-dimensional magnetic point and space groups", *Zeitschrift für Kristallographie* **221**, pp. 77–82](https://doi.org/10.1524%2Fzkri.2006.221.1.77) gives the number of magnetic $(3,3)$ space groups as $1594\ (+57)$ where $57$ is the number of **enantiomorphic pairs**.

There are no enantiomorphic pairs among the 1D line or wallpaper groups, which explains the equality in their respective dimensions, but there are $11$ enantiomorphic pairs of 3D space groups:
$$P4_1,P4_3\ (6)\qquad P4_122,P4_322\ (8)\qquad P4_12_12,P4_32_12\ (8)$$
$$P3_1,P3_2\ (3)\qquad P3_112,P3_212\ (4)\qquad P3_121,P3_221\ (4)$$
$$P6_1,P6_5\ (4)\qquad P6_2,P6_4\ (4)\qquad P6_122,P6_522\ (6)\qquad P6_222,P6_422\ (6)$$
$$P4_132,P4_332\ (4)$$
When elaborated into magnetic groups, these $11$ pairs become $57$, explaining the discrepancy completely; the numbers in parentheses above indicate the number of *pairs* of magnetic groups corresponding to each pair under the BNS setting (verified by the [Bilbao Crystallographic Server](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/cryst/programs/magget_gen.pl)). An enantiomorphic pair of magnetic space groups collapses into one $(4,3)$ space group when time reversal is converted into reflection in the fourth dimension.